# Open all sections in jQuery UI's accordion after page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hello i would like to have jQuery Ui's accordion opened after page loaded. For that i have found the below code on this site.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="../image/logo.png" href="image/logo.png" />
      <title>Survey</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $( function() {
                $('#accordion').accordion({
                        collapsible:true,
                        heightStyle: 'content',
                        beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
                             // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
                            if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
                                var currHeader  = ui.newHeader;
                                var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
                             // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
                            } else {
                                var currHeader  = ui.oldHeader;
                                var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
                            }
                             // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
                            var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

                             // Toggle the panel's header
                            currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top',!isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected',((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

                            // Toggle the panel's icon
                            currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s',!isPanelSelected);

                             // Toggle the panel's content
                            currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active',!isPanelSelected)    
                            if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp(); }  else { currContent.slideDown(); }

                            return false; // Cancel the default action
                        }
                    });
                    $("#accordion> div").accordion({
                        header: "h3",
                        autoHeight: false,
                        collapsible: true,
                        icons: icons
                    });
            });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
          <h3>First header</h3>
          <div>First content panel</div>
          <h3>Second header</h3>
          <div>Second content panel</div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

My difficult concerns how i can proceed to make all accordion opened after page loaded even if all things are right.
Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by "all things are right"? which things ?

Comment: Just say that the post i found on this  site http://jsfiddle.net/soboaz/3gHrv/  correctly runs but what i want is to open all jQuery ui's accordion after  loading page. In that example i have only one that is opened. i hope to be clear. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Just add this line **just after** your `$('#accordion').accordion({` function -- `$(".ui-accordion-content").show();`. [Your updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3gHrv/926/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show the accordion content, like this:

```js
$( function() {
  $('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible:true,
    heightStyle: 'content',
    create: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#accordion .ui-accordion-content').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="../image/logo.png" href="image/logo.png" />
      <title>Survey</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="accordion">
          <h3>First header</h3>
          <div>First content panel</div>
          <h3>Second header</h3>
          <div>Second content panel</div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It is right!